# MySQL relating tables in the database

Tags: php, mysql

In the video tutoria/book I am using to learn about PHP and SQL, the author is explaining the concept of the foreign key to make database tables relate to each other. As you will see in the image below, we are currently making a table called "comments." Within this SQL, there is a line `photograph_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,`called the "foreign key," which the author says relates the "comments" table to the already existing "photographs" table.

My question is, since the table is called "photographs" (plural with an s), but the sql foreign key is "photograph_id", how does SQL connect the two?  What exactly is it about "photograph_id" that allows MySQL to relate it to "photographs" table.

```
+-----------------------------+
| Tables_in_C263430_quoralist |
+-----------------------------+
| photographs                 |
| users                       |
+-----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.21 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE comments (
    -> id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    -> photograph_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
    -> created DATETIME NOT NULL,
    -> author VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
    -> body TEXT NOT NULL
    -> );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MySQL does not "connect" the two tables automatically, you have to do that yourself:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
photograph_id INT( 11 ) NOT NULL,
created DATETIME NOT NULL,
author VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL,
body TEXT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (`photograph_id`) REFERENCES `photographs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

This will tell MySQL that your table `comments` has a foreign key. You didn't specify a name for the key, so mysql will choose a name itself. They key is on the column `photograph_id` of that table. The key refers to the table `photographs`, its column `id`.

Maybe the author meant that you use the column to "emulate" a foreign key, meaning you use that key to join to the primary key of photographs, without really adding the Foreign Key Constraint. So you, the database administrator, know that the field is used for a relation, but the database itself does not (and hence will not check the integrity of the field: you could add a comment to a photograph that does not exist).

Comment: thank you. the author said that the syntax photograph_id which I put in the comments table achieves the connection. Is that correct? if so, why, since not even the spelling is the same. In your example, I see how you use REFERENCEs 'photographs'. Since my SQL does not have that, does that mean my foreign key is not working properly?

Comment: Foreign key's in MySQL take a while to get used to. There are a few requirements (you need innodb as storage engine, to start), which you can find in the [MySQL Foreign Key Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html). The name of the column never creates a foreign key all by itself, but it is a good habit to always name the columns the same way so you can see for yourself it's a FK.

Answer (score 1):

The photographs table may look like this:

```
photograph_id        image_path
========================================
34343                /images/img_343.jpg
34344                /images/img_344.jpg
34345                /images/img_345.jpg
34346                /images/img_346.jpg
34347                /images/img_347.jpg
```

Which is a set of photograph file names stored in database. Note that some people also resort to storing the photograph itself in database in a BLOB format.

When a comment record is created, the SQL is specifying which of the above photograph records to use for the photograph.

Comment: but my question is, how does the syntax photograph_id actually achieve the connection?

Comment: As Konerak mentioned, it is the constraint that extablishes the relationship. Thus, when the comments table is created, one **MUST** map the column `photograph_id` to the one in the photographs table.

Comment: but why MUST one map the column photograph_id to the one in the photographs table and not, for example, to the one in the users table. I don't see how, in the code in the OP, on the level of syntax/spelling, the connection between photograph_id is made to the photographs table.

Comment: The code in the OP is wrong or incomplete! It must specify a constraint else there's no link between the two tables. You could end up having photograph_id values in the comments table that aren't existing in the photographs table. To ensure this mapping, a constraint must be enforced.

Comment: @Michael: You can map it to whichever ID column you want; the point is _you_ have to do it, MySQL won't do it for you. The naming convention is just for you otherwise you could also add comments to your fields should they have unintuitive/funky names.

Answer (score 1):

The actual name of the foreign key field doesn't matter much; it's mostly for documentation. The usual naming convention for tables is that they are the plural of whatever each row represents, while the column name is the singular.

The tables are tied together by specifying a foreign key constraint in the dependent table (comments, in your example). Be aware that the storage engine used for each table affects whether the foreign key constraint is enforced by the system. The default MyISAM storage engine does *not* enforce constraints; the InnoDB storage engine does.

Comment: thank you, but I don't think you actually answered the question, which was how does the syntax photograph_id actually serve as the foreign key, since there is nothing in the code that says "this is the foreign key" connecting it to the photographs table.

Comment: @Michael - I don't know exactly what you mean by "the syntax photograph_id". You seemed to be under the impression that the _name_ photograph_id, in itself, somehow did something. It does not. Perhaps the author should have said something like, "We will tell MySQL to use `photograph_id` in the `comments` table as a foreign key to the `id` field of the `photographs` table." The foreign key is defined by specifying a foreign key constraint when defining (or altering) a table. The answer you accepted shows how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

@Michael: As @Konerak notes, you have to specify it yourself. MySQL creates tables using the `MyISAM` engine by default for which the `FOREIGN KEY` clause is ignored. Both your tables must be `InnoDB`. I suggest you also have a look at this introduction to foreign keys and referential integrity in MySQL -- http://www.techrepublic.com/article/an-introduction-to-foreign-keys-and-referential-integrity-in-mysql/6035435

Comment: o.k., thanks, I'll look at it.  i understand why @Konerak's code would work because it has an explicit REFERENCE to photographs class, but the code I was given does not and it apparently works.

Comment: @Michael: what do you mean, `it works`? Offcourse you could use the key to join both tables. You, the Database Administrator, know about the relationship. MySQL, the RDBMS, does not. That does not prevent you from using joins though :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell it by defining a foreign key. The syntax goes like this:

```
ALTER TABLE comments ADD CONSTRAINT fk_photgraph_id FOREIGN KEY (photograph_id) REFERENCES photographs (id)
```

(You can do the same in one go inside the `CREATE TABLE` statement, but I prefer the above, because this way you can first create all your tables, and then add the foreign keys, without worrying about the correct order).

This will tell MySQL that the `photograph_id` column in the `comments` table links to the `id` column in the `photographs` table. From then on, MySQL will check for you that any `photograph_id` is associated with a valid `photographs.id`; by adding `ON UPDATE` and `ON DELETE` statements, you can control how exactly it does that - for example, if you specify `ON DELETE CASCADE`, then deleting a photograph will also delete all comments that reference it; `ON DELETE SET NULL` will set the comments' `photograph_id` to NULL instead; `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and `ON DELETE RESTRICT` will refuse to delete the photograph until all comments have been removed or assigned to a different photograph. Cascading deletes are very powerful, so be careful when using them. You might delete more things than you intend to, and databases don't have an 'undo' button.

An important point to remember is that foreign keys in MySQL only work with the InnoDB storage engine; MyISAM does not support foreign keys. If you specify a foreign key on a MyISAM table, MySQL will happily parse it and then ignore it without raising any errors.